# Random number between 0 and 1?

Tags: python, random

I want a random number between 0 and 1, like 0.3452. I used `random.randrange(0, 1)` but it is always 0 for me. What should I do?

Comment: @gidim: this is more specific question e.g., `random.random()` (`[0,1)`) is the answer to this question but not the question you've linked and therefore it is not a duplicate.

Comment: randrange(a,b) returns INTEGERS between a (incl.) and b (excl.)

Comment: import numpy as np
np.random.random_sample((120))

Answer (score 369, accepted):

You can use `random.uniform`

```
import random
random.uniform(0, 1)
```

Comment: This just does `return a + (b-a) * self.random()`

Comment: To get always same numbers, ensure to set a seed first, just `random.seed(123)`

Answer (score 123):

`random.random()` does exactly that

```
>>> import random
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print(random.random())
... 
0.908047338626
0.0199900075962
0.904058545833
0.321508119045
0.657086320195
0.714084413092
0.315924955063
0.696965958019
0.93824013683
0.484207425759
```

If you want *really* random numbers, and to cover the range [0, 1]:

```
>>> import os
>>> int.from_bytes(os.urandom(8), byteorder="big") / ((1 << 64) - 1)
0.7409674234050893
```

Comment: random.random return values between [0,1) so then return would never be 1.

Comment: @gidim:  `randrange(a, b)` excludes `b` as well as anything `*range()` in Python. Python uses [option a)](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html). OP shows `randrange()`, not `randint()` that includes both edges.

Comment: Even if it would include, the probability to return 1 would be extremely low (as in practice there is a 64 digits precision of python's float), so it wouldn't change much.

Answer (score 38):

> I want a random number between 0 and 1, like 0.3452

`random.random()` is what you are looking for:

> ***From python docs:***
>   [random.random()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) Return the next random floating point number in the
>   range [0.0, 1.0).

---

And, btw, ***Why your try didn't work?***:

Your try was: `random.randrange(0, 1)`

> ***From python docs:***
>   [random.randrange()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) Return a randomly selected element from range(start, stop, step). This is equivalent to choice(range(start, stop, step)), but doesn’t actually build a range object.

So, what you are doing here, with `random.randrange(a,b)` is choosing a random element from `range(a,b)`; in your case, from `range(0,1)`, but, guess what!: the only element in `range(0,1)`, is `0`, so, the only element you can choose from `range(0,1)`, is `0`; that's *why* you were always getting `0` back.

Answer (score 20):

you can use use [numpy.random](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) module, you can get array of random number in shape of your choice you want

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.random(1)[0]
0.17425892129128229
>>> np.random.random((3,2))
array([[ 0.7978787 ,  0.9784473 ],
       [ 0.49214277,  0.06749958],
       [ 0.12944254,  0.80929816]])
>>> np.random.random((3,1))
array([[ 0.86725993],
       [ 0.36869585],
       [ 0.2601249 ]])
>>> np.random.random((4,1))
array([[ 0.87161403],
       [ 0.41976921],
       [ 0.35714702],
       [ 0.31166808]])
>>> np.random.random_sample()
0.47108547995356098
```

Answer (score 6):

This solution works!

`random.randrange(0,2)`

Comment: For reference, the OP wanted a float between 0 and 1 but this will return a choice between integers 0 and 1.

Comment: How does this answers the question? One is looking for a floating point number between 0 and 1 (exclusive).

Answer (score 2):

**RTM**

From the docs for the Python `random` module:

```
Functions for integers:

random.randrange(stop)
random.randrange(start, stop[, step])

    Return a randomly selected element from range(start, stop, step).
    This is equivalent to choice(range(start, stop, step)), but doesn’t
    actually build a range object.
```

That explains why it only gives you 0, doesn't it.  `range(0,1)` is `[0]`.  It is choosing from a list consisting of only that value.

Also from those docs:

```
random.random()    
    Return the next random floating point number in the range [0.0, 1.0).
```

But if your inclusion of the `numpy` tag is intentional, you can generate many random floats in that range with one call using a `np.random` function.

Answer (score -9):

My variation that I find to be more flexible.

```
str_Key           = ""
str_FullKey       = "" 
str_CharacterPool = "01234ABCDEFfghij~-)"
for int_I in range(64): 
    str_Key = random.choice(str_CharacterPool) 
    str_FullKey = str_FullKey + str_Key
```