# How to generate random number between 0 and 1 in genetic algorithm toolbox, Deap

Tags: python, random, genetic-algorithm

I am using [genetic algorithm toolbox](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deap) in Python. The code:

`toolbox.register("attr_bool", random.randint, 0, 1)` usually defines random numbers of `0` and `1` to be generated. The question is that I am looking for random numbers **between** `0` and `1`. I used `toolbox.register("attr_bool", random.uniform(0, 1))`, but it takes me the below error:
`TypeError: the first argument must be callable`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random number between 0 and 1 in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359740/random-number-between-0-and-1-in-python)

Comment: Look at the 2nd answer not the 1st

Comment: Look at your parentheses. Compare them to the example's parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that it must be able to call the first argument, meaning that it has to be able to act as a function. `random.randint` is a function, but `random.uniform(0, 1)` is not. It's a floating-point number. To fix this, you can simply make an anonymous wrapper function with the `lambda` keyword:

```
toolbox.register("attr_bool", lambda: random.uniform(0, 1))
```

Comment: `TypeError: integer argument expected, got float`.

Comment: May be we should change:

Comment: `toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, toolbox.attr_bool, 100)`
`toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)`

Comment: If it requires an integer, why are you trying to give it a floating-point number?

Comment: Because the parameters should be between 0 and 1. The optimal value also is in that range.

Comment: If it's giving you an error that tells you it needs an integer, I'd say it shouldn't be between 0 and 1.