In Python with numpy, how to get uniformly distributed random floats between 0 and a natural x, including both?
In Python with numpy, for a given natural number x, we'd like to get an array (say, 20×2 or whichever shape you wish) of uniformly distributed floats in the interval [0,x]. Notice that the interval is closed.
Based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/33359758, a completely screwed approach is
x=10
print(np.reshape([int.from_bytes(os.urandom(8))*x/((1<<64)-1) for i in range(40)],(20,2)))

However, the results depend on the operating system. I also don't see whether/why the obtained numbers could be uniformly distributed.
Notice that a (different) approach of somehow obtaining uniform IEEE 754 floats from [0,1] and then multiplying them by x is potentially flawed because, unless x is a power of 2, your numerators (in terms of the representation as numerator * 2^{…}) will always be multiples of x, whereas all non-multiples of x would never show up.
Any help? Pseudo-random numbers would also do (assuming that they are uniformly distributed).
You can also assume that x is small, say, x<2^8, if it helps.

Out of curiosity, why do you need the upper range?

Your question needs clarification. Mathematically, using an open or closed interval makes no difference, as the probability to obtain any real number, including the bounds, is 0. It can matter if you can only generate a finite number of random numbers in this interval. Now, the way you generate these numbers will determine if it is possible to obtain the bounds and what the probability of obtaining them will be, and this has to be your choice. But as already asked: why exactly would it be relevant?

@AndrewYim Nothing special. Sometimes you see closed intervals in your original task (from your teacher/boss/customer), which then translate to the minimal task at hand.

@ThierryLathuille There are only finitely many IEEE floats in [0,x].

That's my point. Whatever method you use, there is only a finite number of possible random numbers you can generate, and this depends on the method you use. So, you have to specifically choose one method, and this will determine the probability of getting the upper bound - if, again, it is somehow relevant.

@ThierryLathuille Our task is to find a method that does deliver the upper bound x, and does so with the same probability as any other float in [0,x]. As measuring radioactive decay is usually unavailable, statistically/practically uniform would be fine. What do you think of jakevdp's solution?

@AlMa1r: A generation procedure that assigned equal probability to every float in the range [0, x] would be extremely biased towards small values, as there are far more small floats than large floats.

Trying to do this runs into issues from both the "ideal real-number distributions" side and the "floating-point realities" side. On the "ideal real-number distributions" side, a uniform distribution over the real-number interval [0, x] assigns a probability of 0 to the output x, and is functionally identical to a uniform distribution over [0, x). Floating-point approximations of these distributions would be identical.

On the "floating-point realities" side, numpy.random.uniform doesn't actually promise that all floats in the output range will actually be possible outputs. For common output ranges, it won't be capable of producing all valid outputs. This is the case for almost every implementation of similar functionality, across languages and libraries. So even with something like jakevdp's answer, there's no guarantee it'll even be possible to get the endpoint value you want as an output.

@user2357112 Good point about a bias towards small values. That's not what we really want. We want uniform distribution approximated by the closest floating-point values. In this case, the probability of getting x would not be zero, as the random reals slightly smaller than x would be approximated to x. I'm thinking of a proper mathematical formulation; if you have one, please edit the question correspondingly.

You could adjust the endpoint to the next floating point number after the max:
import numpy as np

def uniform_with_endpoint(low=0, hi=1, size=None):
  return np.random.uniform(low, np.nextafter(hi, np.inf), size=size)

This gives a uniform distribution in which hi is included in the possible results.

Thx! I was unaware of numpy.nextafter.
